# restore tab key binding to default action

Tags: vim

One of vim plugin added this mapping, which starts auto completion when I press tab.

```
s  <Tab>       * <Esc>i<Right><C-R>=TriggerSnippet()<CR>
```

How do I restore the tab mapping to insert spaces instead of autocomplete. I tried various noremap but it did not take effect or simply did nothing. unmap do not help either.

- Vim version 7.2
- CentOS 6.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `:unmap <Tab>`, considering the mode(s). You've shown the `:smap` (presumably of the snipMate plugin), but the behavior you've described is the `:imap`.

Now, that unmap needs to be done *after* the plugin has defined the mapping, so you can't do that in your `~/.vimrc`. Usually you put the commands into `~/.vim/after/plugin/<pluginname>.vim`, but snipMate already uses such a file to define the mapping! Therefore, choose a name in the *after* directory that alphabetically comes after snipMate, e.g. `~/.vim/after/plugin/zzzSnipMate.vim`.

As you probably want to define different mapping keys for it (otherwise you could just uninstall the plugin, right?), you can do that there, too.

Comment: You were spot on about snipmate. Incidentally after googling hard for it, I got some hints about the problem being snipmate. :verbose imap <tab> actually pointed me to snipmate. Upgarding it to latest git repo, fixed the problem. ~/.vim/after is neat trick I learned today. THanks.

Comment: By the way, what does s in front of map signify? How did you make out that it could be snipMate?

Comment: The s stands for _select mode_, a special variant of visual mode. See `:h map-modes`. I recognized snipMate because I use it, too!

Comment: some how ~/.vim/after did not work for me. I "iunmap <tab>" put ~/.vim/after/zzsnipmate.vim. I tried with unmap as well.

Comment: You can check `:scriptnames` output to verify that your script indeed comes after snipMate. `:verbose imap <Tab>` tells where it got defined.

Comment: the zzsnipmate.vim is not listed in that output.

Comment: Oh sorry, I've missed a subdir. It has to be `~/.vim/after/plugin/zzzSnipMate.vim` (with `/plugin/`).